# Is there any SPV client for ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, clients, synchronization, light-clients, spv

I am looking to move some ETH from an exchange to a wallet for which I control the keys. I don't, however, want to download the whole blockchain.

Is there a good SPV client I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ethereum hasn't yet released features which would provide something like SPV. Instead of SPV it will be called Light Client and the protocol for this being developed is called "LES".

More information on the [ethereum github wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol).

Comment: What's the state of development of light clients?

Comment: @Randomblue there's an experimental branch of go-ethereum. Not yet ready.

Comment: @linagee: Link?

Comment: @Randomblue I'd recommend joining https://gitter.im/ethereum/light-client and helping out there if you want to be more involved with the cutting edge of light-client development. There is no unstable or stable code for this yet, they are at the "just barely implemented EIP in a pre-alpha" point.

Comment: what does "LES" stand for?

Comment: @5chdn Light Ethereum Subprotocol. [Source.](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-(LES))

Comment: Is it even possible to create SPV proof with Ethereum's account model?

Answer (score 2):

[Jaxx by Kryptokit](http://jaxx.io/) might be what you're looking for.